# Not able to approve a redaction

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, revision-redaction

A redaction was carried out by another mod to remove an email address, but somehow something has gone awry, and although it shows in my mod review queue, when I try and approve the action, I get a "No changes found to redact" message.

[image]

Comment: Link to the review queue, please?

Comment: http://sound.stackexchange.com/admin/dashboard

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After a fair bit of thinking about this, I've come to the conclusion that the difficulties here arise from the confluence of several issues:

1. Folks tend to come in with an unfortunate mental model of how redactions (and by extension, revisions) work here.
2. No error or warning when you propose a redaction that will do nothing.
3. The automatic redaction suggestion tool that pops up after a different revision has already been redacted (or a redaction proposed for a different revision) would cheerfully let you submit a do-nothing redaction *even when it already knew that it hadn't suggested any changes*.

So here's what I've done to address them:

1. Guidance *on the redact tool itself*.

   [image: screenshot of new revision tool with inline guidance]
2. [Block submission of redactions that do nothing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316664/redacting-a-post-without-edits-should-show-an-error-instead-of-accepting-for-ano/322581#322581)
3. Block the system from suggesting automatic redactions that will do nothing.

Also made the page responsive while I was mucking about with it. So, lemme know if I broke anything there...

Comment: ... *starts wondering what's wrong with [this revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/322013/2)*

Answer (score 6):

This has happened to me too.  It kind of makes sense that you can't approve what's not there -- there's nothing *to* approve.  When I saw this I rejected the redaction (the only way to clear the flag/notification) and talked with the other moderator about what we needed to do.

IMO the bug isn't that you can't click the "approve" button; it's that the system knows it's going to reject the redaction and yet the redaction exists.  The best fix for this problem -- best for the approving mod *and* best for the redacting mod, because redactions are confusing -- would be to reject the redaction attempt.  The moderator attempting to make a no-op redaction should get an error message, instead of seeing something "work" that doesn't really, only to learn the truth when a second moderator has tried to act on it.  If we have enough information to reject it at approval time, we have enough information to reject it at creation time.

Comment: But Rory clearly said "remove an email address" - so why nothing to approve?

Comment: @ShadowWizard the redaction *comment* says "remove email", but it appears that the redaction didn't actually do that.  The redaction interface is confusing; several moderators have made the mistake of thinking they're redacting a *revision* when what they really need to do is "edit in redact mode" (so to speak).  I suspect that's what happened here.

Comment: In this case it is reacting the original rev after I applied an edit to remove the email. The current rev is rev 2. I started a redaction on rev 1.  So what you are saying is that it reacts all history prior to a rev instead of just one part of the Rev history? So I'd react rev 2 making it the new rev 1?  That is confusing.

Comment: @AJHenderson it doesn't remove the entire revision; it removes the part you redact (by editing it out) from the revision that's shown in the history.  Yeah, confusing.

Comment: So really it is "redact this change from previous revisions". Got it.

Comment: Might be worth changing to a change request for better wording atleast. Nothing on either page remotely seems to indicate the actual behavior.

Answer (score 5):

We're seeing this on Ask Different with one moderator two times a couple days apart.

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/admin/dashboard?flagtype=modrevisionredactionapproval
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/revisions/348560/1
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/revisions/348560/2

I'll reject and queue it up for the other mod to approve. The first moderator did not get a message that there was no diff - it went through to the queue, but the second cannot approve it.

[image]

So the first redaction I made was approvable with a diff. Now the second change should get re-evaluated to provide a proper "diff" and be approvable. Doing to be a bit of a dance to change once - approve - then change the second - approve.

Comment: So far, I'm able to queue up changes and have others approve them, what's broken is another moderator can't queue a change that's approvable by the rest of us.