# Please add documentation about the redaction tool to the moderator help

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools, help-center, revision-redaction

Some of us were trying to figure out how to use the redaction tool correctly, as it can be a little [counter-intuitive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288367/162102), when somebody pointed out the documentation in the [moderator newsletter](http://modnewsletter.stackexchange.com/2016/02/february-2016-newsletter-in-progress/).  That was, in fact, just what we needed -- but, 11 months later, I for one didn't remember that it was there.

Moderators see an additional section in the Help Center for moderator tools.  Could we add the information about this tool there?  I think of the newsletter as a place for *announcements*, but I look for help in the Help Center.  The instructions are already written; a cut/paste (or link) would do the job.

In general, when a new tool is announced in the newsletter, could you please review the documentation you've already written to see if it also belongs in the help somewhere?  I know this does happen sometimes; I don't know how systematic the process is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to come up a lot, so I've written a detailed guide to using this tool. It can be found in the moderator-only section of the help center for your site at /help/redact-revision

There's nothing *particularly* sensitive about the information presented there - as you noted, we've covered this publicly in the newsletter before, as well as [on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191121/allow-moderators-to-hide-a-revision) - but I took the opportunity to flesh it out a bit more, with copious example screenshots and a bit of prescriptive guidance. Hopefully this can serve as a platform for future clarifications and guidance when next we encounter confusion.