# Dealing with highly sensitive personal information in a post

Tags: discussion, moderation, security, revision-redaction

Recently, I found a user had posted a complete copy of their credit card magstripe in a question on Security SE. As I did not have 2k rep on that site at the time I could not force an edit to hide the information.

I flagged the post, commented, edited, and tried to find someone on chat to help with this issue, but it took a while (~12 hrs), during which the complete card data was available (except for their name, which the user redacted, although they had a name on their account).

I reported the issue to the issuing bank, which should reduce the impact, but was this the correct way to handle this, and is there anything I should have done differently? Should a different procedure be followed for credit card numbers than for email addresses?

Comment: Note that, even now, the unredacted post edit history is visible to 10k users. Even non-10k users can see the original if they look at the edit suggestion link.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Irrespective of any actions that you take outside of the site, I think that you should flag the post and ask the moderators of that site to redact the information:

[When to redact revisions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292008/when-to-redact-revisions)

Even if you could edit the information out I think that it should also be redacted from earlier revisions.

Once it gets a mod's attention via a flag they can commence redacting and use their own mod room to get attention of another per-site mod to approve the redaction, and depending on the perceived urgency (this one looks urgent), raise it in the all-sites mod room to get the attention of an SE employee.

Comment: Would the best way to ask the mods be via flagging, or is there a room on chat that is good for raising these kinds of issues?

Comment: If there is a suitable chat room where you (as presumably a non-mod) can raise this direct, then I am unaware of it.  Once it gets a mod's attention via a flag they can commence redacting and use their own mod room to get attention of another site mod to approve the redaction or raise it in the all-sites mod room to get the attention of an employee.

Comment: A flag has been open for several days now, since May 6th.

Comment: @forest I'm trying to contact the Security mods now via the all-sites moderator chat room to see if they have seen the flag that you mention.

Comment: @jrtapsell For really serious cases like this I'd recommend raising a flag and then seeking out any mod in chat. They have some tools that can get ahold of the site mods faster than a flag (as PolyGeo mentioned above)

Comment: We (security mods) were aware of this shortly after it occurred. Unfortunately the redaction tool is being its usual annoying self and not allowing mods to redact. This needs a CM.

Comment: Sorry, for the uninformed, CM?

Comment: @jrtapsell CM = Community Manager i.e. SE staff member