# Redacting a post without edits should show an error instead of accepting for another mod to review

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools, revision-redaction

Redacting a post without edits should show an error instead of accepting for another mod to review.

Seems like that sums up the request.

---

I can go into the post revision history and choose to redact at a revision and then at the bottom go straight to submit for another moderator to review, without changing anything.

Answer (score 7):

As of today, attempting to submit a redaction that does not actually redact anything will present you with a white blank page and <s>a swelling rage</s> an error message:

> No changes found to redact.